# Firebase current user update Phone Number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase Auth and I have a form with two fields name and phone number and onsubmit method and I want to update currently logged in user's phone number and name. But its not updating the phone number on submit. Only successfully updating the user's displayname. Please check the code below. onUpdateProfile is the form submit function.

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onUpdateProfile">
    <input type="text" v-model="profile.name" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." />
    <input type="text" v-model="profile.phonenumber" placeholder="Enter Your phone..." />
    <button  type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

    methods: {
      onUpdateProfile() {
              firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                if (user) {
                  //Getting Current User
                  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                  user
                    .updateProfile({
                      displayName: this.profile.name,
                      phoneNumber: this.profile.phoneNumber
                    })
                    .then(() => {console.log('success})
                    .catch(error => {console.log(error});
                  //Updating User other details on submit
                } else {
                }
              });
            }
    }


    data() {
        return {
          profile: {
            name: "",
            phonenumber: ""
          }
        };
      }
```

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: I want to update the phone number on submit but it's not updating. I tried to log the phone number in the console it's returning null

Comment: You can't change the phone number through a call to `updateProfile`. Instead you should call `updatePhoneNumber`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#update-phone-number

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `updateProfile` to update the `phoneNumber`. You have to use the `updatePhoneNumber` API as Firebase Auth always requires the phone number to be verified before saving it on a user.

This is similar to `signInWithPhoneNumber`.

```
const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput();
const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(...);
firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
  .then((confirmationResult) => {
    // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then complete
    // verification by calling confirmationResult.confirm(code).
    ...
    return confirmationResult.confirm(smsCode);
  }).then((userCredential) => {
    // Phone set on the user.
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

According to the Firebase documentation, it looks like you can only update phone number if you are using firebase-admin. Without it you can only update basic information, such as the user's display name and profile photo URL.

If I am wrong please feel free to correct me.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

---

you are using different names;

in template you have this:

```
v-model="profile.phonenumber"
```

and in the onUpdateProfile() method

```
phoneNumber: this.profile.phoneNumber
```

Comment: after changing the names it's still returning phoneNumber: null after submit

Comment: have you tried printing profile.phoneNumber on the console? is it coming null from the form or the value is there but there is a problem with the updateProfile() merhod?

Comment: can you please share the proper updateProfile() method

Comment: I have logged out the phoneNumber in console its returning null

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```js
async function save(phone: string, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { currentUser:fuser } = firebase.auth();
    if(fuser && fuser.phoneNumber !== phone) {
        try {
            const verifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
                callback: (response) => console.log('callback', response),
                size: 'invisible',
            });
            const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            const id = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phone, verifier);
            const code = window.prompt('Bitte zugeschickten Code eingeben');
            const cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(id, code);
            await fuser.updatePhoneNumber(cred);
            console.log('phone number changed', id, cred, fuser);
            setSuccess(true);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```